# How can I explicitely locate elements using XPath after a certain sibling and preceding another sibling

Tags: xpath

Assume I have such HTML structure:

```
<tr A>
  <td>title="123"
</tr> 
<tr B>...</tr> 
<tr B>...</tr> 
<tr B>...</tr>
<tr B>...</tr> 
<tr A>
  <td>title="456"
</tr> 
<tr B>...</tr>
<tr B>...</tr>
<tr A>
  <td>title="789"
</tr>
```

I want locate all  elements only in first section, after /title="123" but before /title="456". I don't know the exact number 'B' in first section, it could be 4 of 150.

When I use the XPath expression:

```
//*[@title=''123]/../following-sibling::tr[@B][preceding-sibling::tr[@A]]
```

it returns me (in this specific example) 6 elements, cause they all meet the above condition. How can I be more specific and find only 4 elements from the first 'section'?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said which XPath version you are using. XPath 2.0 introduces operators (`is`, `intersect`, `<<`, `>>`) that make this quite easy, for example you could do `($X/following-sibling::node() intersect $Y/preceding-sibling::node())`, having first bound $X and $Y to the end points. Or you could do `$X/following-sibling::node()[. << $Y]`.

In XPath 1.0 you can rewrite `P intersect Q` as `P[count(.|Q) = 1]` but it might be inefficient!

For efficiency you really want to stop scanning the following-siblings once you hit the end point. Unfortunately that's hard to achieve even in XPath 3.0 because you can't write recursive functions: it's easier though in XQuery or XSLT.